# How to connect 'users' table with 'post' table in laravel?

Tags: database, laravel, database-connection, laravel-facade

This is my structure, I want to connect these two tables in laravel, How to do it?

Post Table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('post', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('post_id');
        $table->string('post');
        $table->integer('time');
        $table->string('host');
        $table->integer('vote_up');
        $table->integer('vote_down');
        $table->foreign('id_fk')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Users Table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->date('dob');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "connect these two tables"? Do you just want to create a relationship between the models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you are just pasting in migrations but you do need to have yours `users` table created **before** your `posts` table. I would change

```
$table->foreign('id_fk')->references('id')->on('users');
```

to

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Because Laravel can infer foreign keys:

> Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name
>   of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with _id.
>   However, if the foreign key on the Post model is not user_id, you
>   may pass a custom key name as the second argument to the  belongsTo
>   method

And then all you need in your models is the following:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user that owns the post.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
        // if you want to keep your current structure:
        // return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id_fk', 'id);
    }
}
```

and

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the post for a user.
     */
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
        // if you want to keep your current structure:
        // return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'id_fk');
    }
}
```

You can read more about setting up relationships [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships).

Comment: Thank you so much but i deleted my database and recreated it by using other name and now it shows "[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'chatty' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema =
   chatty and table_name = migrations)



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'chatty' " (chatty is my previous databas)

Comment: This would probably be best as a separate question but did you change your `config/database.php`?

Comment: No that one is my mistake sorry i found the mistake now but back to my previous question I tried like you commented, but it doesnt work

Comment: class Post extends Migration{
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    public function up(){
         Schema::create('post', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('post_id');$table->string('post');$table->integer('time');$table->string('host');$table->integer('vote_up');$table->integer('vote_down');$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');$table->timestamps();});}  
    public function down(){
         Schema::dropIfExists('post');}
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');}}

Comment: please update your question with the code, it is extremely hard to read like this. Also please add what error or issue you are getting.

Comment: Alex Harris Can i get your facebook name if you don't mind?

Answer (score 0):

In your posts table you should have:

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
```

on your User model:

```
public function posts(){
return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

on your Post model:

```
public function user(){
return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Comment: Or you could keep your table structure and define the foreign key on the relationship:  `public function posts(){
return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'id_fk');
}` `public function user(){
return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id_fk');
}`

Comment: Thank you so much but i deleted my database and recreated it by using other name and now it shows "[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'chatty' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema =
   chatty and table_name = migrations)



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'chatty' " (chatty is my previous databas)

Comment: In console run composer dump-autoload

Comment: [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists (SQL: create table `users` (`
  user_id` int unsigned not null, `name` varchar(255) not null, `dob` date not null, `email` varchar(255) not null, `
  password` varchar(255) not null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` time
  stamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists

Comment: After following what you have said this is what i got